# Make A Hashmap with its keys being Strings values being HashSets

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

Trying to make a Hash Map with keys of strings, and values of HashSets. I want the hash sets to be all integers

```
Set<String> numbersSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

// won't work:
HashMap<String, numberSet> database = new HashMap<String, numberSet>();//error - "( or [ expected"

//Also won't work. If it did, how can even I add to the set inside this hashMap?
HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>> database = new HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>(); //error-incompatible types
```

Comment: `Map<String, Set<Integer>> mapOfSets = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>(); Set<Integer> numbersSet = new HashSet<Integer>(); mapOfSets.put("numbersSet", numbersSet);`, works for me.

Comment: Luiggi, you should make that an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>> database = new HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>>();
```

Works for me.

BTW, if you are using JDK 1.7 you can use:

```
HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>> mymap = new HashMap<>();
```